# Erro ao concatenar string em jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho dois valores que quero incluir em uma string:

`json[key].id` que é do tipo integer

`json[key].descricao` que é do tipo string

tenho uma variável que recebe esses valores assim (recebendo apenas o id) e funciona perfeitamente:

`linha += "<td><a href='#' onclick='excluiFeira(" + json[key].id + ")'>Excluir</a></td>";`

porém (creio que seja erro de concatenação), quando eu incluo a descricao, o código não funciona:

`linha += "<td><a href='#' onclick='excluiFeira(" + json[key].id + ", '" + json[key].descricao + "')'>Excluir</a></td>";`

recebo o erro:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já está usando aspas simples no `onclick`, não pode usar o mesmo para os parâmetros. Use as aspas duplas e faça o escape:

```
linha += "<td><a href='#' onclick='excluiFeira(" + json[key].id +
", \"" + json[key].descricao + "\")'>Excluir</a></td>";
```

Comment: funcionou, só que, ao invés de usar as aspas simples `\'`, tive que usar as aspas duplas `\"`

Comment: pode corrigir a resposta que dou seus pontos

Answer (score 2):

Aconselho a utilizar [*Template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) que acaba por ficar bem mais fácil de construir as strings que pretende.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
linha += `<td><a href="#" onclick="excluiFeira(${json[key].id},'${json[key].descricao}')">Excluir</a></td>`;
```

Diferenças a salientar utilizando template literals:

- Os delimitadores passam agora a ser os `` ` `` que fazem com que não tenha que escapar `'` com `\'` ou escapar `"` com `\"`
- Cada vez que precisa de colocar um valor dentro da string faz `${valor}`
- Estas strings também são multilinha  o que lhe permite dividir o texto entre várias linhas caso precise.

Veja este exemplo a funcionar:

```js
let key = 'chave';
let json = {
  chave: {
    id: 36,
    descricao: "teste"
  }
};

let linha = `<td><a href="#" onclick="excluiFeira(${json[key].id},'${json[key].descricao}')">Excluir</a></td>`;
console.log(linha);
```